# How to get a value from an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In the following example, Can `-207.500000` (just the value) be gotten from the saved file,`(NPY File (.npy))`, without `[' ']` structure?

```
Slice_num = np.load("Slice_num.npy")
B = Slice_num[person][i, [1]]   =>   B: ['-207.500000'] , <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: slice it once more: `B[0]`

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add one more B[0]:

```
Slice_num = np.load("Slice_num.npy")
B = Slice_num[person][i, [1]]   =>   B: ['-207.500000'] , <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
B[0]
```

and use float to get the value:

```
float(B[0])
```